# mongoDB - what is the best way to check enter/exit polygon events for many locations?

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, polygon

I'm working on a projects where I have many vehicles (around 2000) and several polygons on my DB (working with mongo).

I have different kinds of polygons (cities, countries, intersections...), let's say 4 types for that matter.

Each minute I get the new location of the vehicles and I need to show on a table on the client side the current country, city, and intersection (or last intersection). All I really want to know is when vehicle enter/exit polygon.

I know it's possible to query the current polygon for specific location of vehicle, but I need to get current 4 polygons types for 2000 vehicles.

That's 8000(!!!) DB's query every minute.

What is the best way to do what I want?
thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a better solution because vehicles can't change their city/country frequently until they fly. I am considering below schema-

```
Country={
      id: ObjectId or String, 
      name: String, 
      cities: [<array of city subdocuments>],
      near_country: [<array of IDs of neighbour countries>],
      boundary: location boundary for city <city would be polygon or your choice of geoType>
}
```

City subdocument inside country can have schema like `{id, name, boundary, near_city}.` I will choose my Vehicle schema as `{id, location_cordinates, curr_city, curr_country}`

Now when you get vehicle location data, just fetch curr_city from stored vehicle document and check if location is still inside curr_city. If it is then no issue, else you just need to check if the location is inside any of near_city.

If city/country changes due to vehicle movement then you need to update vehicle with latest data.

In this way you will minimise queries on DB. It would require some code because everything won't be done in DB.

Here I have taken few assumptions like-

- location of vehicle will be stored in vehicle document. If it is not your case then just remove it. You might be getting location from GPS or similar thing and need not to store it depending on your need.
- I couldn't understand the intersection part. Is it transition or intersection? Usually Country has states, state has cities and so on. City name can be duplicate inside a state or across states. But a city will be part of only single state. If that is not the case then you just need to put same city in multiple countries and put code logic to handle those cities.
- While taking near city, you need to consider cities which are on country boundary and might have near city from another country.

Hope I understood your problem and solution helps to you. I would be glad to help further if I get further information.